# highest weight representations inside tensor product

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a semisimple simply connected group over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero, $B$ a Borel and $T$ a maximal torus.
Let $\lambda,\mu,\nu$ be dominant characters of $T$.
Let $V(\lambda)$ be the irreducible representation of highest weight $\lambda$.

If $\lambda=\mu+\nu$, then we know that $V(\lambda)$ is the direct factor of multiplicity one inside $V(\mu)\otimes V(\nu)$.

Is it possible to characterize $V(\lambda)$ inside this tensor product ?

Comment: What kind of characterisation do you hope for?

Comment: You seem to be assuming $k$ to have characteristic $0$, is this correct (in which case it would be a good idea to add it to the question).

Comment: for example there is a finite group acting on the tensor product wich eliminates everything but $V(\lambda)$.

Comment: @prochet:  I don't really understand what you mean by 'eliminate' in your comment.  However, another possibility might be this:  If $R\subset \mathsf{S}(\frak{g}^\ast)$ is the ring of $\mathrm{Ad}(G)$-invariant polynomials (for example, the Casimir would be an element of degree $2$), then $R$ acts as a commuting ring on $V(\mu)\otimes V(\nu)$, and you could, perhaps characterize $V(\mu{+}\nu)$ as the space of elements $s\in V(\mu)\otimes V(\nu)$ that satisfy $r(s) = h_{\mu{+}\nu}(r)s$ for the appropriate 'eigenvalue' homomorphism $h_{\mu{+}\nu}:R\to k$.

Comment: How $R$ acts on this tensor product?

Comment: @prochet:  Identify $R$ with the sub-algebra of $U(\frak{g})$ that is generated by the so-called Casimir elements.  Then the action of $U(\frak{g})$ on $V(\mu)\otimes V(\nu)$ is just the tensor product action; now restrict it to $R$.

Comment: @prochet: I guess all you can say here is that $V(\lambda)$ is characterized as the unique direct summand of the tensor product involving the highest weight (in any direct sum decomposition into irreducibles).  (Also, your tag 'lie-groups' should be replaced by 'algebraic-groups', given your assumptions.)

Comment: @prochet: By the way, the tag 'ag.algebraic-geometry' is also unneeded here and could be replaced by 'lie-algebras'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand my comment (and Robert Bryant's) a little further, the main point here is that tensor products of *finite dimensional* irreducible representations behave nicely.  In the equivalent Lie algebra setting, the finite dimensional irreducibles are those whose highest weights are *dominant integral* in the dual of a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{t}:= \mathrm{Lie} \;T$ of $\mathfrak{g} := \mathrm{Lie} \;G$, relative to some fixed choice of positive (or simple) roots.

In particular, $V(\mu) \otimes V(\nu)$ has highest weight $\lambda:= \mu + \nu$ with multiplicity 1.   The complete reducibility of this tensor product depends mainly on the fact that the center $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ of the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ (generated by "Casimir operators") acts by distinct central characters on the distinct finite dimensional representations.  In other words, the sum of all copies of a typical $V(\pi)$ in the tensor product decomposition is a single "eigenspace" for the action of the center, where the action is given by a "central character" $\chi_\pi$.

Since the summand $V(\lambda)$ occurs only once in the tensor product (the weight space for $\lambda$ being one dimensional), $V(\lambda)$ may be characterized as the set of all vectors on which $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ acts by the central character $\chi_\lambda$.    (There may of course be many isomorphic summands of smaller highest weights $\pi$, where the center acts by the single character $\chi_\pi$.)    In different language this is essentially Robert's comment.